# Leaflet control layer update

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am using this example to setup a control layer.

http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html

```
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

How do I just update overlayMaps with latest markers? In other words, the user may or may-not have the overlayMaps "checked" and I just want to update the markers based on latest data.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`L.Control.Layers.addOverlay()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#control-layers-addoverlay) and [`L.Control.Layers.removeLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#control-layers-removelayer).